# How to build Xamarin Forms App with Linker enabled and resolved dependency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, linker, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I've developed many Xamarin Forms Apps but this time I'm getting a big issues as I'm not able to reduce the size of the app. I've integrated many other nuget packages and sdk like onesignal for push notifications, Amazon AWS S3 for files upload and show etc. The problem is, When I integrate the SDK in a test app then it successfully builds and all done but in my main project I'm having error. In Android, Onesignal shows error and so when I disable linker then it works and in iOS Amazon S3 SDK shows error and when I disable linker then it works fine. But the size of the app increases too much and which is not acceptable. I've also tried skipping the assemblies option but that again don't work. :(

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. This is a common problem. Without more details on what your build configuration options are between Debug and Release, you could try referencing the library explicitly in the code:

(Source: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/11/dealing-with-the-linker-in-xamarin-apps/)

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include()
    {
        var x = new System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter (typeof(void));
    }
}
```

I also suggest you have a read of the following documentation for ideas to help, there are a number of things you can do:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/